# Python SQL cursor/fetch: When does the database query complete running?

Tags: python, sql, db2, cursor, fetchall

I had a question regarding the python IBM_DB package (but I think it could be applied to any of the packages that employ the connection/cursor logic i.e. pyodbc).

When the cursor.execute() method is called, it executes an sql query on the database. However, to access this data, you would need to use the fetchall()/other fetch methods. I want to time the hit on the database.

Does the query completely finish running at the execute level, and it is in memory just for python to fetch? Or does the fetch method continue calling the database? I have scoured the documentation and am unable to find anything definitive on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Most or all of the [Db2 open source drivers](https://github.com/ibmdb/) are based on the [Call Level Interface (CLI)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/c0007944.html?pos=2). The [CLI functions and details](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000553.html) are part of the overall Db2 documentation. The [Fetch()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000591.html) from a ResultSet retrieves one more row.
AFAIK the result set can be cached or go back to the engine. It makes sense to bring in few (dozen) rows, but not for some million rows.

You would need insights and understanding of how drivers and database query processing work in order to measure something useful and interpret it correctly.

BTW: There is some form of CLI tracing available.